# how can I forward all routing to a path in the public directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a javascript frontend application that lives in `/public/app/`

Basically, I just want to do something like:

```
route.get '*', :to => '/public/app/index.html'
```

so that going to any path will result in the index.html being loaded, and the js appication will handle the routing at that point...

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you do it? Yeah probably. It's a tremendously inefficient way to serve a SPA though compared to just having the web server serve the file though.

Comment: Agreed. Probably want to look at a simple load balancer like Nginx or Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going through rack and rails stack just to render a static file for all requests. Do you need rails at that point?

But, technically, it is doable:

```rb
get "(*path)", to: ->(env) {
  # status, headers, body
  [200, {}, [Rails.root.join("public/app/index.html").read]]
}
```

**Update**

You can use `constraints` to skip asset requests for this route:

```rb
constraints(path: %r{^(?!/app/assets)}) do
  get "(*path)", to: ->(env) {
    [200, {}, [Rails.root.join("public/app/index.html").read]]
  }
end
```

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-constraints*

Comment: As hinted in earlier comments it would be way more efficient to just separate out your SPA from Rails and use the web server (or SAAS) to serve the file directly. There are also tons of options for serving the application in development like [web-dev-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@web/dev-server). Many frameworks like Ember and Vue also come with a built in CLI that will serve your app in development.

Comment: Probably want to catch all verbs e.g. `match '(*path)',via: [:get,:post,:put,:delete]...`

Comment: I do need rails because I have an api server.  I am trying to make all non matched routes for /api get forwarded to `public/app/` The problem with the above code is that because index.html has script and style tags, those requests are all receiving index.html again as a response.  I tried checking env['PATH_INFO'] to see if it has an extension and if so, serving that file but then I am getting `server responded with a MIME type of ""`  -- despite providing the correct mime type in the headers object via: 'Content-Type' => Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES[file_ext] ... any ideas?

Comment: @patrick see update.

Comment: The problem is the mime type issue... I am doing: `[200, { Content-Type' => Rack::Mime.mime_type(extension) }, Rails.root.join(File.join('public', 'app', path)) ]` ... and I see for something like "/scripts.f994bc696f8b2c5a.js", the headers object is: `{"Content-Type"=>"application/javascript"}` .. which is correct...  Yet I get: "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

Comment: The content-type is being set..  I did `curl -i localhost:3000/scripts.f994bc696f8b2c5a.js` and I see `Content-Type: application/javascript` ...... but for whatever reason the browser thinks it has a mime type of ""

Comment: I opened another question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77191319/rack-app-serving-js-file-with-content-type-set-yet-browser-says-mimetype-is