# rack app serving js file with Content-Type set yet browser says Mimetype is ""

Tags: ruby, mime-types, rack

I have a rack app:

```
class Responder
  def self.call(env)
    path = env['PATH_INFO']
    path = File.extname(path).blank? ? 'index.html' : path
    extension = File.extname(path)
    headers = {
      'Content-Type' => Rack::Mime.mime_type(extension)
    }
   [200, headers, [ File.read(File.join(APP_ROOT, path)) ] ]
  end
end
```

The goal of this is that any route like `/foo` or `/bar` will respond with `index.html` and otherwise any request for `.js` or `.css` the file requested will just be passed through...

When testing this, I see the correct content type in the headers being set..  And I can even see this with curl:

```
curl -i http://localhost:3000/foo
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
```

and

```
curl -i http://localhost:3000/main.js
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

Yet when I try to view the application in the browser, any script tags that are calling for javascript files are failing with errors saying:

```
main.js:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Why does the browser claim the server is responding with a MIME type of "" when curl is showing the server is responding with "application/javascript" ?

Comment: are you sure those requests actually hit your Responder. static files, if they exist, are served way before routes in `ActionDispatch::Static` middleware. and every which way i've tried it, it works just fine. "main.js:1 Failed to load module script" - importmaps issue? is that error from the `main.js` file itself or from one of the imports in `main.js:1`?

Comment: Are you sure you really need to reinvent the wheel here? [Rack::Static](https://rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Static) has this use case pretty well covered. But as per your previous questions using Rack for a job that can be done by much more efficiently by Apache/NGinX or SAAS services is kind of bonkers.

Comment: @max, it's not bonkers at all.  There is a feature test suite that needs to interact with the front-end application for local development environments where nginx is not running.

Comment: @patrick there is an entire plethora of tools that can be used to run your SPA in development...

Comment: and I am using those tools.  I needed a way to serve the files for the test environment...  I don't think you understand, but it's cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the mime type stuff to work by using actual Rack::Request / Rack::Response objects.

```
  get '(*path)', to: ->(env) {
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    response = Rack::Response.new
    extension = File.extname(request.path_info)

    if extension.blank?
      content_type = Rack::Mime.mime_type('.html')
      filename = 'index.html'
    else
      content_type = Rack::Mime.mime_type(extension)
      filename = request.path_info
    end

    response.header['Content-Type'] = content_type
    response.status = 200
    response.write File.read("public/app/#{filename}")
    response.finish
  }
```